# SearchBoxEX SearchResultPageURL

Tags: search, search-results

I am us a 'SearchBoxEX' control on my site. Since my site has a language variation, I use a resource files to specify the 'SearchResultPageURL' property.

The page is located on the root of each variation:

ie. "http://.../en-US/SearchResults.aspx"
ie. "http://.../fr-FR/SearchResults.aspx"

How do I specify the URL in my resource such that it is a relative URL that will always point to the correct 'SearchResults.aspx' regardless on which sub-site I may be on.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware that needs to be set at site collection level.

[[source]](http://mmman.itgroove.net/2012/04/powershell-to-update-the-search-target-for-a-site-collection/)

PowerShell script to do it.

```
$site = Get—SPSite "http://[site]"
foreach ($web in $site.Allwebs) {
    Write—Host "Modifying all search result pages in site ($($web.Url))"
    $web.AllProperties["SRCH_ENH_FTR_URL"] = http://[searchsite]/
    $web.update()
}
$site.Dispose()
```

**Also:** You can also set this to happen on a Web Provisioned event receiver for new webs.

Comment: There are two different pages, depending on whether sites exist under the variation or not. It is up and running, however I specify the full URL to the page. If I ever change IP for example, I will need to update the resource file. How would I, for example, specify a link on a page to always go to the root-site level, without specifying the entire URL?

Comment: Why don't you use relative URLs? Under /_layouts/enhancedSearch.aspx "Example: /SearchCenter/Pages or http://server/sites/SearchCenter/Pages"

Comment: I had tried that, turns out I forgot the initial "/". Thanks, for the help.